# unmarshal json array of records with inner arrays (all integers)

Tags: arrays, json, go, unmarshalling

I am trying to write a simple go program to read json and unmarshal to a slice of Record structures from this data

```
[
[[[1084, 1347], [1365, 717, 293]], 30], 
[[[768, 989], [562,555]], 10],
[[[4, 1144], [1355, 1279, 298]], 20]
... many more records
]
```

data is an array of records
each record has a two element array of ints, 
then a variable number of element array of ints, and then a int
All data in the arrays are ints

I can't figure out how to read the inner arrays of each record using the json libary.

Of course can read them as strings and do the parsing work, but it seems that the json library should do all the lifting for me.

Trying to read each record into

```
type Record struct {
    pair struct{
        x int
        y int
    }
    vector []int
    result int
    }

...
records := make([]Record) // variable to receive all records
```

Please Help.

Comment: You must EXPORT your fields!

Comment: You could use https://github.com/tidwall/gjson to parse jsons without defining any structs

Comment: I did just figure it out. You just need to unmarshal to type  interface{} see playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dA84P4gnwcA, works with only about 6 lines of code to unmarshal.